# in Backbone model, which method gets executed first, success or parse?

Tags: backbone.js, model, fetch

I am making a AJAX call using something like:

```
model.fetch(
      dataType: "jsonp",
      success: function(data){}
)
```

My question is if I want to modify the data return from the server, should I do it in success or model.parse(). Also, which method gets executed first?

WARNING: I am a backbone newbie :)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse will be triggered first.

The backbone official documentation its not clear about it. It says:

**parse is called whenever a model's data is returned by the server, in fetch, and save. The function is passed the raw response object, and should return the attributes hash to be set on the model. The default implementation is a no-op, simply passing through the JSON response. Override this if you need to work with a preexisting API, or better namespace your responses.**

It doesn't talk about who is triggered first.

But i test it by my self, and parse was triggered first.
You can test it by yourself, if you don't have an API for test, Use dataType:"jsonp" and try to find a web site that is using REST.You'll see that JsonP is triggered first. :)

Comment: Thank you so much!Just tested, you are right.Parse gets triggered first